# youtube api uploads.gdata.youtube.com taking very long even for small file then aborts

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I have this application using youtube .net api to upload videos to youtube channel

some days earlier it was working fine.

but suddenly it stopped working

and when uploading files using youtube api using multipart/form-data and action as https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload/sometoken?nexturl=http%3a%2f%2fexample.com

it just does not upload and in firbug net panel it shows this

[image]

the last yellow request is to youtube and it continues for like 30 mins while video is for 1.5 mb . and after that it shows aborted.

what is the solution to this or any troubleshooting help??